# Varchar, Char or Binary to improve MySQL Performance

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, varchar

I'm using MySQL and I'm reading in some places that using `CHAR` in indexed columns is 20% faster than use `VARCHAR`. In other places seems that its benefit is only when the table doesn't have any `VARCHAR` column. Is that true?

The information that I want store is a GUID. Is a better option store the data in a `BINARY` or in a `CHAR` if the database uses character set utf8? It's worth convert my data to `BINARY` every time that I want insert, update or query filtering by the GUID? I prefer faster data access than save disk usage.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Check those out. Looks like binary will be a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks, it seems better use BINARY, but is really better BINARY that VARBINARY? Is it faster convert the GUID to a 16 bytes length BINARY or save it like a 34 bytes BINARY?

Comment: `BINARY` is the fastest way to store the GUID information, if you are into micro optimizations. `BINARY` vs `VARBINARY` - `BINARY` is yet again faster because MySQL won't have to compute the actual length it has to save since all `BINARY` columns will be of the fixed-width.

Comment: Then, if I have a table with 3 `VARCHAR` columns and a `BINARY` column and I do a query filtering by the `BINARY` column it will be faster? The other columns don't matter?

Answer (score 5):

Any fixed-width column type will lend itself to faster seeking operations when compared to variable-width types. Unless your table is partitioned, it is also true that the variable-width types can degrade performance even on operations which do not involve them. For consideration, think through the algorithm for how you would iterate all the values in a column when all columns are fixed-width and then when some aren't:

For all-fixed width tables (or partitions), you might use simple pointer arithmetic, where you add the value of the combined data-width of all the columns in the partition each time through the loop.

If there are any variable-width columns, however, you would need to calculate the amount to add to the pointer every iteration, based on the actual on-disk "width" of the columns.